# How do I force IE and/or Microsoft Edge to reload PAC file

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am using automatic configuration script hosted on my server. It's configured to use proxy on URL pattern, but it seems that it failed. More on the problem, it previously works on IE11 when I still use Windows 8.1, after upgrading to Windows 10, the pac file seems ignored.

Is there anyway I make sure that PAC file is used or is there a way to make IE or Edge force reload PAC file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't get Microsoft Edge to use the PAC file I set in Internet Settings. It will use the proxy server though. IE 11 on Windows 10 shouldn't have problem using the PAC as it did in Windows 8. If it doesn't, check if `Automatically detect settings` is enabled and try disabling it.

To make sure IE uses the current PAC file, you can disable caching:

```
Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings

Value: EnableAutoproxyResultCache (REG_DWORD)
```

1 (default) = enable caching and 0 = disable caching

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could reliably force a reload of the PAC script by...

1. going to proxy settings,
2. deactivating the PAC,
3. reactivating the PAC,
4. hitting Save.

[image]